Vue: nginx setting works in development mode, fails in production mode
I have a nginx configuration like this:
server  {
  server_name lionchortle.lol;

  location ~ ^/vue  {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
  }


  location ~ ^/vue/  {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
  }

  location ~ ^/page  {
    root  /lionchortle;
    try_files $uri.html $uri =404;
    index index.html;
  }


}
...

I have the following directory hierarchy:
/
  lionchortle
    page.html
    vue
      src
      package.json
      node_modules
      ...

When I deploy Vue project in development mode:
npm run serve -- --port 8085

going to http://lionchortle.lol/vue shows the starting page of the Vue app.
However when I try to deploy in production mode:
npm run build
npx serve dist -l 8085

I can only see the Vue project by going to http://lionchortle.lol:8085. Going to http://lionchortle.lol/vue shows the page like this:

404 the requested path could not be found.
Going to http://lionchortle.lol/page always works (shows the page.html).
Why does switching to production mode makes the nginx configuration break?

The only thing that i can think of is that you did not define root directive on location ~ ^/vue/ .
When the root directive is not defined in an Nginx configuration, Nginx will try to serve content from a default location on the filesystem. The default location varies depending on the Nginx installation and the operating system.
So my suggestion is to define root after server_name directive. something like this :
server  {
  server_name lionchortle.lol;
  root  /var/www/lionchortle;

  location ~ ^/vue  {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
  }


  location ~ ^/vue/  {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
  }

  location ~ ^/page  {
    root  /lionchortle;
    try_files $uri.html $uri =404;
    index index.html;
  }


}


there are reason that I think can be solved this

You need to set the name of service of your project instead of localhost on the NginX then  you need to set inside port of your service on nginx

like :
location ~ ^/vue/ {
     proxy_pass http://<your_service>:<inside port>
}

